# How to make an integer displayed separated by ","?

Tags: output-formatting

I would like an integer to be displayed in output like this, with "," separating the integer.

> eg.   256,856,669,999,887,878,452
>   eg.   23,242,456

However, I can't find any option.

[image]

Is it possible for mathematica to display integers the way I need?

Comment: use `NumberSeparator` https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberSeparator.html

Comment: Go to Preferences, and change the Digit block separator field.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html) with the option `DigitBlock`.

```
 NumberForm[20!, DigitBlock -> 3]
```

[image: big_int]